# Magento 2 : "The file was not uploaded." error on mageplaza blog module

Tags: magento2, mageplaza

**Steps to reproduce**

Create a blog post without image
Save
or...

Create a blog post including image
Save
Open up for editing
Save it again

**Expected result**

Blog post should save the updates
Actual result
Magento throws an exception "The file was not uploaded."
So basically the module always expects a new image to be attached to a post even if there already has been uploaded an image to it.

**Exception:**

> Exception #0 (Exception): The file was not uploaded.
>   #1 Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader->__construct('image', &Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database#0000000060cfa2ea000000004348112d#, &Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage#0000000060cfa511000000004348112d#, &Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension#0000000060cfa510000000004348112d#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111]

Comment: Have you fix it?

Comment: Yes please check answer. That worked for me

Comment: Can you send mageplaza blog module link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, please download and replace attach files:

Media.php: **Mageplaza/Core/Helper/Media.php**

**[Media.zip](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog/files/3231686/Media.zip)**

Please check it again, you will see it work normally.